# Override nextjs-Sourcecode

Tags: next.js, node-modules

I have an issue in my next.js-Application that might be only being fixed by a small adjustment to the next.js-Source-Code.

For simplicity I reduced the amount of code a little bit:

```
export class Head extends Component<HeadProps> {
...
return (
      <head {...getHeadHTMLProps(this.props)}>
...
     {head}
        <meta
          name="next-head-count"
          content={React.Children.count(head || []).toString()}
        />

        {children}
        {optimizeFonts && <meta name="next-font-preconnect" />}
...
```

Original Source:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/pages/_document.tsx

I need to swap the position of `{head}` with `{children}` (for various reasons) - that's all I want to change.

So I need to override the Head class of _document.tsx.

What is the **correct / best way** to do this in my next.js-Application?

Note: I am fine with the fact that I might need to adjust this override with a newer next.js-Version

Kind regards,

Comment: While technically you could extend the existing `Head` class to override any desired methods and use it in `_document`, I'd highly recommend you didn't do it. What's the reason you want to change how `Head` works in the first place?

Comment: My project consists of multiple microservices. One microservice is providing some styles that are necessary for the final view of my nextjs-Application.
I can't include the styles via styled-jsx due to another problem I faced.
However if I just place it inside of the <head>-Tags it get's placed before all other styles of my project (for example Bootstrap).
Thanks for your comment! Will post my result here soon.

Comment: Don't you have control over where the Bootstrap and your microservice's styles get imported? How are you importing the styles in your Next.js app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to override the order in *next/head* by using a **npm-module** named *patch-package*. https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

That allowed me to create my own patch for the nextjs-Sourcecode.

So the patch was moving *{head}* downwards (switching the position with some other included tags there) and the result was exactly what I was looking for.

Small - but for me acceptable - downside: The -Tags of my nextjs-Application are now also moved a little bit downwards in the -Tags.
However I don't have to "fight" styles that were coming from my nextjs-Components now.

Answer (score 0):

This is in my opinion not possible with nextjs!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).